# Excel find a value in a column with wildcard characters

Tags: excel, formula, wildcard

I have a column of values (a list of numbers), within that column some of those values repeat but with letters on the end of them so if my first value was 123 in that same column on row 34 I may have 123A or 123B (letter is random). I was hoping to find said values in the column by using a simple formula, something like `=XMATCH(A1&"*",A$1:A$4,1,1)` to look at a possible match with a wildcard at the end, but that didin't really work. Any ideas how I could approach this?

Comment: Needs to be like this `=XMATCH(A1&"*",A$1:A$4,2,1)` ==> **[XMATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xmatch-function-d966da31-7a6b-4a13-a1c6-5a33ed6a0312)**

Comment: That returns the first occurrence, you could use `=FILTER(A1:A4,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1&"*",A1:A4)))` ==> will give the repeated values as an output

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya you don't really need a wildcard with search. It's also not quite the same as the original formula, which would only find items **starting** with that number.

Comment: Ah yes, absolutely i missed that. yes as per OP's explanation it seems `123` will always be in the starting